# Unresolved external symbol __glewBindBuffer

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dll, linker, glew

I am getting an error with visual studio. Does anyone know how to solve this error?

All the files are included in the linker but I am still getting this error. I am using the x64 platform.

Check the image

[error LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __glewBindBuffer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMIZ0.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: Please do a basic search of this site (or via your favorite web search engine) for the error message before posting a new question. Chances are that it has been asked about here before. Also, [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). You'll find your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting, as was suggested when you created your account.

Comment: No this is not my answer. I already check that but it's not my answer.

Comment: Yes, it is - it provides all the information that you need to solve the problem. And you couldn't possibly have read every single answer to that question in 10 minutes.

Comment: I already check that answer before I post my question.

Comment: Then check it again.